# Remover focus de elemento usando JavaScript puro

Tags: javascript

Quero saber como remover o foco de um elemento quando ele for clicado usando JavaScript puro.

Eu fiz dessa forma usando jQuery

```
$(function(){
  $(".btn").click(function(){
    $(".btn").blur();
  });
});
```

Isso me servia muito bem, porém, alterei algumas coisas no site e o jQuery ficou quase sem utilidade. Seria um exagero incluir o jQuery em um site apenas para fazer isso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente isso, é proposto para caso você tenha vários elementos com a `class="btn"`. Você vai usar a mesma função `blur()`:

```
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++){
    btn[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
         this.blur();
    });
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente!

Answer (score 2):

Esse código jQuery faz 3 coisas:

- espera que a página carregue para correr o código
- adiciona um oscultador de eventos a cada elemento com a classe `.btn`
- remove o foco, ie faz `.blur()` a todos os elementos com a classe `.btn`

Presumo que no terceiro passo só seja interessante tirar o focus ao elemento clicado, e não perder tempo com os outros. Podes fazer isso assim em JavaScript nativo:

```
window.onload = function () { // só corre quando a página tiver carregado
    function blur() {
        this.blur(); // o JavaScript nativo também têm este método blur   
    }
    var btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
    for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) { // percorre todos os elementos
        btns[i].addEventListener('click', blur); // adiciona o auscultador de eventos
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A função é a mesma: [**`blur()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Events/blur).

Exemplo:

```js
var button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.blur();
});

button.addEventListener('blur', function() {
  alert('Perdeu o Foco.');
});
```

```html
<button>Remover foco</button>
```

Para pegar todos os elementos você pode usar `document.querySelectorAll`.